# How to access element props react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I declared a top bar element like this.

```
export default Class MyClass extends React.Component {
  static router = TopTabNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return() {
      <View>
        <TopTabNabiagtor
          navigation = {this.props.navigation}
          data = {this.state.data}
        />
      </View>
    }
  }
}
```

and still don't know how to access the ***data props*** from the creation of TopBar.

```
const TopTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1: {
            screen: props => <Tab1 {...props} information = {props.data.information} />,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: "Tab1"
            }
        },
    },
```

Data props is undefined, I might wrong when accessing the props, did anyone know how to solve it...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve because it would seem that you already are accessing the data props. You have `information={props.data.information}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass them in a specific way and that is by using `screenProps`, if you don't they may not get there.

The documentation explains it how to pass `screenProps` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props

## Code Changes

In `MyClass` pass the props that you wish to pass in the following way

```
<TopTabNabiagtor
  navigation = {this.props.navigation}
  screenProps = {{data: this.state.data}}
/>
```

You don't need to do anything special when you create your `TopTabNavigator` you should just be able to access them directly in the `Tabs` by doing the following

```
this.props.screenProps.data.information
```

## Example Code and Snack

Here is some example code, which I have also made into a handy snack for you. https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/passing-props-through-a-navigator

### App.js

```
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
      data: { key: 2345, name: 'John'}
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <AppContainer screenProps={{data: this.state.data}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

### MainNavigation.js

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: props => <Screen1 {...props} /> // you can set up the screen this way
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2 // or you can set it up this way, I usually set it up this way
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1'
}

const MainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens,config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

### Screen1.js

```
export default class Screen1 extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.screenProps.data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```